# Populating LoginContext

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas, gssapi

Is there anyway i can populate a LoginContext rather than using the callbackhandler? my program will recieve username and password (what the callbakchandler deals with),i want to use them rather than manually input the information.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See the [MyCallbackHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) example.